# Did Thanos pick them on purpose or was it random?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

At the end of [*Avengers: Infinity War*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avengers:_Infinity_War),

> Thanos' plan comes to fruition as people begin disintegrating, including Bucky Barnes, Drax, Groot, Mantis, Maximoff, Parker, Quill, Strange, T'Challa, and Wilson.

Could this be caused by Thanos' direct manipulation or does it happen without Thanos' interaction but as some random event?

> The heroes getting disintegrated, was it because it was Thanos's choice to complicate the possible regrouping of the Avengers/Heroes or was it just random?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The available evidence suggests that they were randomly selected.

When Thanos meets Doctor Strange on his (former) homeworld, he talks about the solution he had proposed (which was rejected) to resolve the problems caused by its overpopulation. That solution was to

> kill half of the population, who would be selected in a "lottery, fair to rich and poor."

We also see the same thing occurring to

> Gamora's homeworld in a flashback to when she was a child.

Given that his original plan was for it to be random, I think it's reasonable to conclude that that's still the plan. Besides,

> they weren't able to stop him from obtaining all of the Infinity Stones when **all** of them were alive. There's no reason for Thanos to care which of them survive and which don't.

Comment: Personal opinion without any real back-up here, but Thanos possibly doesn't care any more. He has done his part, and will sit back and watch the grateful universe unfold into a paradise. What does it matter to him whether he actually has the stones or not (apart from possibly the green one...)?

Comment: I almost 100% agree, with two exceptions: Thanos specifically didn't kill Iron Man, and himself.

Comment: Yes. Thanos is a monster, but he made a deal with Strange that he clearly wanted to keep.

Comment: @AlexRuyven: He didn't kill iron man personally at the end of their fight. It is not clear whether he excluded iron man from the finger click.

Comment: Why "(former)"? Isn't it still his homeworld?